# Why is `explicit` not compatible with `virtual`?

Tags: c++, function, c++11, virtual, explicit

```
struct A
{
    // error C2216: 'explicit' cannot be used with 'virtual'
    virtual explicit operator bool() const 
    {
        return true;
    }
};

struct B : A
{
    // error C2216: 'explicit' cannot be used with 'override'
    explicit operator bool() const override 
    {
        return false;
    }
};

int main()
{
    if (A())
    {}

    if (B())
    {}
}
```

My compiler is VC++ 2013 RC.

Why is `explicit` not compatible with `virtual`?

What's the rationale?

Comment: Looks like MSVC bug, since works fine in gcc and clang.

Comment: You can work around this using NVI.

Comment: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/805301/explicit-cannot-be-used-with-virtual
Still not fixed in VC2017

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Looks like a bug, since the following quotes prove that they are indeed compatible, and I couldn't find anything to disallow it.

#### 12.3.2 Conversion functions [class.conv.fct]

> 2) A conversion function may be `explicit` [...] 
>   [...] 
>   5) Conversion functions can be `virtual`.

and

#### 7.1.2 Function specifiers [dcl.fct.spec]

> 5) The `virtual` specifier shall be used only in the initial declaration of a non-static class member function;
>   see 10.3.
>   6) The `explicit` specifier shall be used only in the declaration of a constructor or conversion function within
>   its class definition; see 12.3.1 and 12.3.2.

Comment: The reason for this bug is probably that pre-11 `explicit` could only be used with constructors, which cannot (or should not?) be virtual anyway, so they made the additional rule of disallowing `virtual` and `explicit` together right away and this rule was just not updated when introducing `explicit` operators in *VC 2013*.

Comment: yeah But why can't I just create a virtual contructor in a base class, and later implement it in the actual class.